# Unable to Deploy Rails Appication in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to upload a Rails 5.2 Application in Heroku however, I'm unable to deploy it. I am using Rails 5.2 and Ruby ruby '2.5.1'

Below are the logs request your kind assistance.

Thanks!

```
Peeyushs-MacBook-Air: peeyushverma$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1642, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1588/1588), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1642/1642), 8.01 MiB | 257.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1642 (delta 684), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Could not find rails-assets-jquery-3.3.1 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Could not find rails-assets-jquery-3.3.1 in any of the sources
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/.git'
```

Comment: Can you write a [mcve] of this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `assets/javascripts/application.js`, try to replace `//=require jquery` with `//=require jquery3`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `//=require jquery` or `//=require jquery3` from `assets/javascripts/application.js` and use rails default `//= require rails-ujs` and try to deploy again.